# How to extract PPM Image Properties from an ImageMagick Wand using C?

Tags: c, image, imagemagick

In order to convert almost any type of image into a PPM I'm using ImageMagick's wand API. 
From the wand how do I extract the PPM properties of width, height, modval and raw RGB data?
Here is some skeleton code.

Many thanks in advance for reading the question.

```
  /* Read an image. */
  MagickWandGenesis();
  magick_wand = NewMagickWand();
  status = MagickReadImage(magick_wand, argv[1]);
  if (status == MagickFalse)
    ThrowWandException(magick_wand);

  /* TODO convert to P6 PPM */

  /* TODO get PPM properties */
  ppm->width = ...
  ppm->height = ...
  ppm->modval = 3 * ppm->width;
  ppm->data = malloc(ppm->width * ppm->height * 3);
  /* TODO fill ppm->data */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From ImageMagick Forum](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=18262#p69822)

```
width = MagickGetImageWidth(magick_wand);
height = MagickGetImageHeight(magick_wand);
ppm->width = width;
ppm->height = height;
ppm->modval = 3 * width;
ppm->data = malloc (3 * width * height);
status = MagickExportImagePixels(magick_wand, 0, 0, width, height, "RGB",
            CharPixel, ppm->data);
```